# L1B with a role change

Tags: indian-citizens, l1-visa

I have been working as a Software Engineer for an American company in India for the past 5 years, and have been offered a Program Manager position at Headquarters for the product I currently use in my daily job. (For instance, I use Visual Studio in India, and have been offered a PM position on the Visual Studio team)

Informally I've heard that a L1B is used primarily for moving without a change in role...  is a role change atypical and will it result in needless complexity during the visa interviews,etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, L1 is a visa to transfer people with specific knowledge/expertise between the branches. So if you're transferring into a new position, and your expertise for that position is of a "user", expect troubles explaining why you're needed in the US both to the USCIS (may be easier given lawyers will write tons of stuff which may have nothing to do with reality) and to the visa officer (that's where you may get stuck).

Comment: Interesting.. thanks.  When you say visa officer, do you mean the interviewer at the embassy, or the interviewer when entering US?

Comment: in the embassy.